# Create a SPA static serverless application with F#

Tags: f#, single-page-application, fable-f#

What I am trying to do is to write an SPA application in F#. Is it possible to use Fable without the full tooling, just only as F# to html+javascript compiler?
Ideally I would like to be able to compile one or more F# files into a static html+javascript markup and send it straight to the browser from F# interactive, without any web server.

The typical workflow is:

> 1) Create new project from template
>
> 2) Modify project files
>
> 3) Build
>
> 4) Open browser and point to specific url

What I would like to do is something like (from F# interactive):

```
let html = Fable.compile([fileXYZ.fs])
do XPlot.Plotly.Html.showInBrowser html "pageid"
```

Is this possible?
How can I do it?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "full tooling". Which specific tools would you like to avoid?

Comment: The full Fable tooling doesn't actually require a Web server. The reason why [instructions like these](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-templates/tree/master/simple/Content) have you point a browser at `http://localhost:8080/` is because *during development*, having a server process allows for watching your source files, recompiling when you edit a file, *and* automatically refreshing the browser after the compile finishes. But ultimately, Fable just compiles to Javascript, which could be served up from a static HTML file just fine.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The way I read it, the question is "how to invoke Fable as a library" (taking F# source code and producing JS). This looks like a reasonable question to me, but alas, I don't know the answer.

Comment: @Tomas yes the "way you read it" is correct.

Comment: @munn that would be my assumption too, yet I couldn't find an example not following the "full tooling" pattern

Comment: The problem I see would be that the Fable compiler does not emit JavaScript but rather Babel ASTs which Babel in turn takes to produce valid JavaScript. I'm not aware of any case in which the Fable compiler generates html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked for the same in the past as sometimes the requirement is just to transpile a single file (Azure DevOps extensions for example).

Sadly, the current answer is "no".

The question is still open today: https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/1369

People have build prototypes: https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/fantasy

But I don't think you can answer with a "yes" at this time.

I hope this helps.